# How to avoid multiple decimal points using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a textbox in which I would like to restrict the number to allow only one decimal point.

I have used regex to handle this but when I try to give the input it doesn't allow.

Whereas if I start with a decimal point it allows.

I would like to have the output as:

```
1.33
12.33
```

But it works like

```
.33
```

Code:

```
  const onlyNums = value.replace(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/, '');
```

Comment: what's your input? what do you mean by allows when you are using replace?

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `^\d+(\.\d+)?$` is a regex for *validation* as it matches the whole string starting with digits and optionally followed with `.` and 1+ digits. It is not meant to *replace* (or *sanitize*). Please provide a valid attempt and show the whole relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the regex, you can simply check if the `Number` equals the input's value without strict type checking. As soon as the user enters a second dot (or something else than a number), this returns false

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
 console.log(Number(e.target.value) == e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<input id="foo">
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it will work , replace this regex

/^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$/

Comment: How is this different from OP?

Comment: What should this regex be replaced with?